# Spread operator "is not defined" when trying to omit property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react, i'm trying to do something that should be very simple: use the spread operator (...) to create a copy of an object OMITTING ONE PROPERTY...

I've tried to follow some posts here, when i test then in javascript emulator they work, but they dont work in my real case

```
const obj = { a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'};
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({a,...obj});

console.log(formData);
```

I get the error

Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: For that to work, you have to destructure, not spread

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you teach how to do?

Comment: The problem is the `a` variable inside the `useState` that is undefined, try to declare it before or after the obj

Comment: Did you read the linked question that shows how it works?

Comment: I had read them before and yet it doesn't work... say that a is not defined.... Is it native javascript or do i need to use a specific framework?